# How to plot line to join three coordinates in matlab

Tags: matlab

How can I plot a line between three or more coordinates? For example, I have four points, (a1,b1), (a2, b2), (a3, b3) and (a4, b4), how can I join these points starting from (a1, b1) to (a4, b4)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

English is not my native language so please be patient.

Make two vectors like :

```
x = [a1,a2,a3,a4];
y = [b1,b2,b3,b4];
```

Then plot a 2D line.

```
figure
plot(x,y);
```

If you need more help, please check the reference from [MathWorks](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com).